# Verify Cognito identity in PHP backend API

Tags: php, android, amazon-cognito

I have bit of a confusion here, I am working on an android application, with PHP backend. I use other AWS libraries for most of the tasks but transactions and etc I kept for backend. I use retrofit for handling PHP api calls and responses. I am quite confused here, is there any way where I can determine cognito identity id of user making request to my web API using PHP? Using API gateway I will be able to restrict access only for logged in users, but determining their identity is receiver API is quite confusing for me.

Update :
I do not wish to use API gateway in any term. It's buggy most of time requests times out. Server provides better performance for current situation.

Any clue or help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I use cognito for my companies browser and mobile applications. Do you already have a user database? or will you be using cognito to also store your user data?

Comment: I have user database in dynamodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a user database, you will need to use "developer" identities in Cognito.

You need to create an "Identity Pool" in the "Federated Identites" section of Cognito.

From there you register a "Custom" authentication provider.. Basically it's a string that you will associate your users ID with...

Then you will use the CogintoIdentity->getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity() method to sign in your users in amazon.

You will be returned an IdentityID and an OpenID session token that you can send to STS to get temporary credentials to the AWS API... you can also use this new identity to create datasets associated to the Identity with CognitoSync

```
$cognitoIdentityClient->getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity([
    'IdentityPoolId'=>'Your Pool ID',
     'Logins'=>[
          'your.custom.provider.string'=>'YOUR USER ID'
      ]
 ]);
```

EDIT:
After obtaining an IdentityId... In my mobile application, I use custom HTTP Headers to send over the IdentityId, and also the User ID and use "lookupDeveloperIdentity" method to validate the user on the server side.

```
$cognitoIdentityClient->lookuoDeveloperIdentity([
    'IdentityPoolId'=>'Your Pool ID',
     'DeveloperUserIdentifier'=>'{X_HTTP_USER_ID}',
     'IdentityId'=>{X_HTTP_COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID}
      ]
 ]);
```

Comment: I am already doing this on android side. I have register identity provider and created user identities. Now I want to identify user who is making post request to PHP for their valid identity ID. What do I need to pass to POST request to get their identity from cognito? Guess it's openID token, will try it and let you know. :)

Comment: What I do is add the identity ID and the UserID in custom HTTP Headers..... then I use the method "lookupDeveloperIdentity" to verify the user sending the request